# Static:: on private members

Tags: php, static

Is there any meaning to it?

```
public static function a(){

  static::_b();

}

private static function _b(){

}
```

static here is same as self in any situation, because you cannot override a private function in the child class, right?

Comment: 1) You can not override static method/function (it is hiding, not overriding).  

I am not with you on your statement "static here is same as self", what did you mean? To me your `static::_b();` looks like a local method hiding externally defined `function _b()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Germann Arlington said in the comment. A subclass can have it's own implementation of _b() - even with a different visibility.

```
<?php
class Foo {
    public static function a() { static::_b(); }
    private static function _b() { echo 'Foo'; }
}

class FooEx extends Foo {
    public static function _b() { echo 'FooEx'; }
}

FooEx::a();
```

prints `FooEx`

Comment: For some bizarre reason I have always just assumed that you cannot override (or hide, whatever) static methods. Every day's a school day. +1